# How to use an Angular variable to control the index of an angular array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to show some information about an item, and if I click in a list of other items the information must change (not the case right now).

To show the first item of an array is easy if I use 0 between [ ], but if I try to use the $scope.id = 0, nothing happens.

HTML:

```
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <b>{{faturas[{{id}}].faturan}}</b>
                        <p>Vencimento: <span>{{faturas[{{id}}].venc}}</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <p>Período: {{faturas[{{id}}].ini}} a {{faturas[{{id}}].fim}}</p>
                        <p>Valor: R$ <span>{{faturas[{{id}}].valor}}</span></p>
                    </div>
```

Node:

```
var queryString = 'SELECT * from faturas WHERE empID = '+usuarioSession.empID;
connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows)     {  
    var ret = [];              
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {                        
        ret.push ({
            index: i,
            faturan: "Fatura "+(i+1),
            venc: rows[i].fatDataVenc,
            ini: rows[i].fatDataIni,
            fim: rows[i].fatDataFim,
            valor: rows[i].fatValor
        });

    }         
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    response.end(JSON.stringify(ret), 'utf-8');
});
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('faberto',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.id = 0;
    $http.get('/servico/faberto').success(function(data) {
        $scope.faturas = angular.fromJson(data);

    });
});
```

Comment: first of all, you can't use an expression `{{ }}` inside another expression, so instead of `{{faturas[{{id}}].faturan}}`, you should use `{{faturas[id].faturan}}`.  However, the larger question is why you wouldn't use `ng-repreat` for this kind of operation instead of accessing items by their array index.

Comment: @Claies is correct.  Use ng repeat and then you can use $index if you truly need the index.  Most of the time you don't though.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I didn't know that would be better using ng-repeat in this case, usually I use to print all the "list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Claies said, you can't use a `{{ }}` inside another one! Check this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/mHNaTXBNfzTGD3T0ujHY

I've created a mock to show you how `ng-repeat` would be more suitable for the situation!